# Proof that dot product is not symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra

If you define 
$$u = [0,1]$$
$$v = [1,0]^T$$
then clearly $$v \cdot u = 0$$
but $$u \cdot 
v = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 && 0\\
    1 && 0\
\end{bmatrix}$$
I know I am just confusing notation but can someone please clear this up for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We wouldn't define $v$ the way you have. Rather $v=[1,0]$ and THEN the dot product is defined by $u\cdot v = u^Tv.$  Likewise the $v\cdot u = v^Tu.$  You put the $T$ in too soon.

Comment: Oh, so In my case $u \cdot v^T = u^Tv^T $?

Answer (score 1):

These are two different products. In general, matrix multiplication does not commute.

The inner product of two vectors is $u^T v$ which returns a scalar. The outer product, $uv^T,$ returns a matrix. Just remember that order matters in matrix/vector multiplication.

The usual dot product does commute - write $u^T v = (v^Tu )^T$ by properties of matrix multiplication. But since both are scalars, they must be equal.